# How to restrict the Microsoft Graph API access scope to a specific Sharepoint when using delegated permissions?

Tags: security, sharepoint, permissions, microsoft-graph-api

When accessing the Microsoft Graph API via **Delegated permissions**: how to restrict the application access to a specific Sharepoint?

Currently I'm using the access scope `Files.Read.All` but I want to restrict the read access to just one specific Sharepoint as I just need this single Sharepoint Read access. Getting more access is more unsecure. Currently the access token retrieved by my desktop application might be stolen and used to get all data the user has access to.

In [Permissions naming pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-overview?tabs=http#permissions-naming-pattern) the `{constraint}` value seems to give this possibility but I didn't found more detailed information there.

Microsoft introduced `Sites.Selected` scope for  Graph **Application permissions** in 2021, see [Controlling app access on a specific SharePoint site collections is now available in Microsoft Graph](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/) but I couldn't find this for **Delegated permissions**.

I had a look at [Microsoft Graph permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference) but didn't find the required scope there.

Comment: When you mention Sharepoint, do you mean a site collection? or a library? 
Well, what you are describing is the correct usage of the delegated pattern. You delegate access to the app on your behalf and if for any reason your token gets stolen, you can either cut off the access to the underlying account or make tokens shortlived.

`Sites.Selected` are reserved for application permissions, when you have the client credential flow.

Comment: @jimas13 Thanks for your comment. My current interest is a library. I think usually you will not know when a token gets stolen. The token itself is by default already a short lived one (currently about 1 hour). This gives some kind of security but it's enough time to get data in scope of the account / app / token which is why I search for a possibility to further restrict the scope to a specific Sharepoint (library).

Comment: Have you checked this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/how-to/token-cache-serialization?tabs=aspnetcore#quick-summary   ?

Comment: also, there might be a bit of confusion, but generally `Files.Read.All` does not mean that you have access to all of the files. It simply means that you have access to all of the files that the user account has. If you hand out folder based permissions you might achieve a level of seclusion but this will come at the different costs.

Comment: I checked your link above. It's another way to make a token storage more secure. Nevertheless it's adding more complexity. In regards of secure token persistence I also had a look at the follow up documentation: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/Cross-platform-Token-Cache
I'm aware about ``Files.Read.All``does not give permission to something the user has no access to, hence there is far more access possible than required by the app.

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: @RaytheonXie-MSFT I'm still searching for a possibility and aiming to restrict the access scope to a specific Sharepoint when using delegated permissions.